# PHP - Validar solo letras con espacios, evitando un input vacio

Tags: php, validación, input, preg-match

Apenas inicie en `PHP` y para entender mejor estoy practicando con un proyecto de POS.

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo dos `input` uno con "nombre" otro con "usuario"

```
static public function ctrCrearUsuario(){
    if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){
        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÓÍÚ\s]+$/', $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
            preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) &&
            preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"])){
        }
```

Cuando ingreso un nombre y usuario como "Camilo Loco" no tengo problemas, pero cuando ingreso un espaciado como esto " ", se me valida y yo no quiero eso, porque carga en el sistema un usuario vacío.

Y me gustaría si alguien conocedor que haya experimentado lo mismo, me pueda ayudar a que solo se valide el espacio cuando tiene letras.

Comment: Antes de hacer ese regex, puedes primero hacerle un trim() a nuevoNombre y ver si está vacío o no

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te ha servido, puedes aceptarla y darle al upvote, de esta manera servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes. En caso contrario, tienes la libertad de dejar comentarios pidiendo explicación o incluso puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/584444/edit) tu pregunta para mostrar avances. Finalmente, te sugiero hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas mejor la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

La función `trim()` limpia los caracteres en blanco de la cadena de caracteres.

Luego, la función `empty()` evalúa si la variable está vacía, o el valor es nulo.

El siguiente ejemplo retorna: **Camilo Loco**

```
<?php
  $var = "  Camilo     Loco   "; // Lo que llega por POST
  $nombre = trim($var);
  // Validar si viene vacía
  if (empty($nombre)) {
      echo 'Variable vacía';
  } else {
    echo $nombre;
  }
?>
```

En cambio, el siguiente ejemplo retorna: **Variable vacía**

```
<?php
  $var = "     "; // Lo que llega por POST
  $nombre = trim($var);
  // Validar si viene vacía
  if (empty($nombre)) {
      echo 'Variable vacía';
  } else {
    echo $nombre;
  }
?>
```

Posteriormente puedes hacer el `preg_match()` para evitar la inserción de otros caracteres indeseados.

Answer (score 0):

Para PHP sugiero el uso de algún framework como [LARAVEL](https://laravel.com/), u otro similar, pero como aprendizaje puedo sugerir hacer una recuperación del valor a evaluar con un reemplazo de espacios en blanco y/o algún otro carácter que necesites eliminar:

```
static public function ctrCrearUsuario() {

    $strNuevoUsuario = $_POST["nuevoUsuario"];
    $strNuevoUsuario = str_replace(' ', '', $strNuevoUsuario);

    if(isset($strNuevoUsuario)) {
      ...
    }
}
```

De igual manera se puede implementar el mismo procedimiento para los **inputs** que necesites, vuelvo y repito este trabajo se hace más sencillo con el uso de un framework, debido a que cuentan con capas de validación muy versátiles y eficientes.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `str_replace(' ', '', $strNuevoUsuario)` también elimina los espacios en blanco que hayan entre las palabras. Si llega por `post` el ejemplo que facilita el OP, las salida sería **CamiloLoco**

Answer (score 0):

Te han dado respuestas en el lado del backend, con `trim()` puedes prevenir que no lleguen cadenas que empiecen con espacios al servidor.

Por el lado del *fron-end* también podrías poner un regex a los input con la propiedad [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).
Dale a *Ejecutar* para probar.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nuevoNombre" pattern="[^\s][a-zA-Z ]+" required>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Por supuesto, se podrían hacer validaciones más avanzadas con Javascript.